# Real time datagridview in dotnetcore

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am new in dotnetcore 2.1 and I have worked earlier on winform's DataGridView. I was able to update winform's DataGridView very easily but I am not able to do the same task in dotnetcore 2.1 Web project.

Please guide me and provide me some useful link by which I can create real time datagridview in dotnetcore. I have searched on google and come across pusher but this is quite expensive for me.

Please guide me. Thank you!

Comment: The client is a webapp?

Comment: @NicuVlad yes! dotnetcore webapp

Comment: I just added https://datatables.net/ in my project 2 days ago. I'm very happy with the result and easy to implement.

Comment: @NicuVlad but this data table is not free of cost. I want something free.

Comment: It's free. Actually I just saw that you can pay for it. But I just downloaded the libraries and I can use it: https://datatables.net/download/

Comment: You can check if like it using the CDN files https://datatables.net/manual/installation. And you can copy and paste one of their examples.

Comment: From what I see you need to pay only if you want to post something on their forum.

Comment: Did you managed to get it going?